# What is the difference between left join (table1, table2) and left join table1 left join table2

Tags: mysql, sql, database

What is the difference between the two sql queries?

```
select * from a
left join (b, c)
on a.id = b.uid and a.id = c.uid

select * from a
left join b on a.id = b.uid
left join c on a.id = c.uid
```

Comment: The first query is not valid ANSI SQL.

Comment: It works in mysql5.7.@jarlh

Comment: Still a bad idea to write non-portable code when you can do it correct without any extra effort.

Comment: If you run `EXPLAIN EXTENDED...` followed by `SHOW WARNINGS;` it should give you a clearer idea of any functional difference.

Comment: Thanks,I will try it.@Strawberry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets have this data:

```
A       B        C
id      uid      uid
--      ---      ---
 1        1        2
 2
```

---

First, the second query:

```
select * from a
left join b on a.id = b.uid
left join c on a.id = c.uid

 ID UID  UID
 -- ---- ----
  1    1 NULL
  2 NULL    2
```

This should come as no surprise - second column is joined from `b` and where there's no data in `b`, `NULL` is used (outer join); third column behaves the same, just for `c`.

---

The first query, rewritten with `CROSS JOIN` (which it is equivalent to) to be ANSI-compliant:

```
select * from a
left join (b CROSS JOIN c)
on a.id = b.uid and a.id = c.uid

 ID UID  UID
 -- ---- ----
  2 NULL NULL
  1 NULL NULL
```

Why there are all `NULL`s?

First, the CROSS JOIN is performed, but that results in a resultset with just one row:

```
b.UID   c.UID
-----   -----
    1       2
```

Then, the left join is performed, but there's no row in the result of the cross join that would have same `uid` for both `b` and `c`, so no row can be matched for either row in `a`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 select * from a
 left join (b, c)
 on a.id = b.uid and a.id = c.uid
```

is equivalent to

```
select * from a 
left join (b cross join c)
on (a.id = b.uid and a.id = c.uid)
```

Here you can find the details
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Comment: Thanks. Can I get the result from a even b or c has no additional data by my second sql?

Comment: I think, you got your answer from @Jiri Tousek